# how can a Class.forName returns a Class<? extends MyAbstractClass>?

Tags: java, generics

Let's say I have an abstract class `MyAbstractClass`:

```
public abstract class MyAbstractClass {
   public abstract SomeObject doSomething();
}
```

and I have some concrete implementations of this class, `MyConcreteClass1` and `MyConcreteClass2`.

Let's say I read the class name of any of the concrete implementations from a file and then I want to create the object:

```
String concreteImplementationName = getConcreteImplementationName();
Class<?> klass = Class.forName(concreteImplementationName);
```

I get the Class and then using reflection I can instantiate an object.

Now, in this case I know that the `concreteImplementationName` will only contain the name of one of the implementations of `MyAbstractClass`. How can I convert `klass` to a `Class<? extends MyAbstractClass>`?

```
Class<? extends MyAbstractClass> x = // what do I need to do here?
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [`Class.asSubclass`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#asSubclass%28java.lang.Class%29) to do this. It works similarly to a cast, but for a Class object.

`c.asSubclass(T.class)` will check that `c` is *actually* a subclass of `T`, and if so it will return a `Class<? extends T>`. Otherwise it will throw a ClassCastException.

So you want this:

```
Class<? extends MyAbstractClass> x = klass.asSubclass(MyAbstractClass.class);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add a cast. You can do this safely because you know it's a subtype of `MyAbstractClass`

```
public class Example {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String concreteImplementationName = "com.example.Implementation";
        Class<? extends MyAbstractClass> x = (Class<? extends MyAbstractClass>) Class.forName(concreteImplementationName); // what do i need to do
    }
}

class Implementation extends MyAbstractClass {
}

class MyAbstractClass {
}
```

Comment: Note that this will *not* throw an exception if the Class object isn't for a class extending MyAbstractClass. (and so you'll get an "unchecked cast" warning)